# iOS 9: UIPrintInteractionController presentation issue

Tags: ios, printing, ios9

I'm struggling for few days with this extremely strange issue. Here is the standard code for initializing and presenting print dialog, which was perfectly working before iOS 9:

```
- (void)setupPrinting:(UIPrintInteractionController *)aPrintController
{
    NSString *text = [self formattedHTMLforPrinting];
    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *formatter = [[[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:text] autorelease];
    aPrintController.printFormatter = formatter;
}


- (IBAction)printContent:(id)aSender {
    if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]) {
        UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
        printController.delegate = self;
        [self setupPrinting:printController];

//tried different ways to present print controller
//        [printController presentAnimated:NO completionHandler:nil];
//        [printController presentFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES

//these two lines are just to make sure printButton is not nil
        self.printButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.printButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

        [printController presentFromRect:self.printButton.bounds inView:self.printButton animated:YES
            completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *aPrintController, BOOL aCompleted, NSError *anError)
            {
              NSLog(@"printing is done with error: %@", anError);
            }];
    }
}
```

On iOS 9 Print dialog displays wrong and can not be dismissed tapping outside modal view has no effect - the app becomes unresponsive.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue with latest version of iOS. Can you please help me out in this? How have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is the cancel & print buttons are being clipped by the modal window, leaving you stuck in that view. If anyone runs into a similar issue, check if you're setting a fixed width on your `UINavigationBar` class. Once you update that, the buttons should come back in the modal.